# wxPerl install on Mac

Tags: installation, wxwidgets, cpan, cpanm, wxperl

I've been able to install wxWidgets on my Mac and use wxPython just fine, but now that I'm trying to use Perl, I need to download wxPerl. I tried to install and the install failed, and I'm not sure what went wrong or how to fix it. Can you help? Here is the terminal output. I can share the error log if needed, but it's pretty long. It's also worth noting that I still had this problem with cpan and with downloading the .tar file and building from that.

```
dhcp86-242:214_Final_project cat$ cpanm Wx
--> Working on Wx
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MD/MDOOTSON/Wx-0.9932.tar.gz ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Alien::wxWidgets
--> Working on Alien::wxWidgets
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MD/MDOOTSON/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Alien-wxWidgets-0.69 ... OK
Building and testing Alien-wxWidgets-0.69 ... FAIL
! Installing Alien::wxWidgets failed. See /Users/cat/.cpanm/work/1525284354.35567/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Alien::wxWidgets' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for Wx-0.9932.
```

---

The "fatal error"

```
../src/osx/core/bitmap.cpp:39:10: fatal error: 'QuickTime/QuickTime.h' file not found
```

A common warning

```
../include/wx/any.h:611:5: warning: expression with side effects will be evaluated despite being used as an operand to 'typeid' [-Wpotentially-evaluated-expression]
WX_DECLARE_ANY_VALUE_TYPE(wxAnyValueTypeImplVariantData)
^
```

The end of the log

```
10 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [coredll_core_bitmap.o] Error 1
system: make all: 512 at ./Build line 67.
-> FAIL Installing Alien::wxWidgets failed. See /Users/cat/.cpanm/work/1525284354.35567/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
-> FAIL Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Alien::wxWidgets' is not installed
-> FAIL Bailing out the installation for Wx-0.9932.
```

I can share more of the warnings if that would help.

Comment: which version of OSX do you use? It would be nice to see the log as well, at least the part with the error...

Comment: I'm running MacOS Sierra version 10.12.6. I'll add the log.

Comment: the log is cut off at the top. Can you add more lines at the top? Also what version of wx wxPerl is built on? You might need to build it yourself.

Comment: The log has 14874 lines. Which ones do you want?

Comment: As for the version, it looks like wxPerl supports wxWidgets 2.8.12 and 2.9.4. I'm not sure which version of wxWidgets I have downloaded, but I would think an installer for wxPerl should take care of prerequisites. But clearly it messed something up. I did try building manually, but I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like whichever version of wxWidgets that is being used here doesn't include the fix from [this commit](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/817bd0076f61ed96694ec6cebba46ca5df495998) (from almost 4 years ago) which is required to build with macOS Sierra or later.

AFAIR, you should be able to get 3.0.4 release, build it yourself and then point Alien to it.

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded wxWidgets 3.0.4, so how do I build it and point Alien to it?

Comment: @CatherineD, buiding is easy: `cd wxWidgets-3.0.4 && mkdir buildMac && cd buildMac && ../configure --with-cocoa --macosx-version-min=10.8 && make`. After that finishes check the documentation for Alien on how to point the tool to the resulting libraries.

Comment: How do I point Alien to the library? I can't find any section on that.